# Dual Resistor in Series with Diode

Tags: resistors, diodes

I am aware of voltage signals being clipped when inserting a diode in series, however, I have been struggling for a few hours to clarify the behaviour obtained by adding a second resistor in series. The clipping seems to be replaced by amplitude reduction. Can some please explain this behaviour and how to calculate this amplitude reduction?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to estimate the diode as a switch as follows;

- for Vd > Vf, Vf=0.6V + Rs ~ 10 Ohms  ( small signal diode )    ( so Vf=0.7 ~ 10mA)

  - Rs rises to the leakage value as Vf reduces from 0.6 to 0
- So for positive swings, there is no load, Vp=5V
- so I guess  Vp-= -2.5-0.6=-3.1Vp maximum 
  and depending on the diode perhaps -2.9V.

You can compute the incremental Rs of the diode to be 1k and determine Vf at that value to be more precise.

Comment: I am in line with your thoughts, but for clarity: the -2.5 is due to the fact that there are two equal resistors? What happens if R2 is 10kOhm? Thanks!

Comment: Then Vp(-)= R2/(R1+R2)Vin - Vf